# Host key verification failed with SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my computer via OpenSSH on Ubuntu (either remotely or from the same machine, different terminal), however none works. When I try to connect remotely with `ssh username@ip_address` the terminal keeps waiting but nothing happens. When I try to connect from the same machine with `ssh -v localhost`, I get the following output and error:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ybhcdw75C5wG/KnILBWaRnIA+NH8kGBFbi8yUIbUhl0
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ybhcdw75C5wG/KnILBWaRnIA+NH8kGBFbi8yUIbUhl0.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

How can I solve this issue? I tried to turn password authentication off, to get the least secure but usable setup, but still no luck.

### Update:

I generated keys and now I get a different error with `ssh -v localhost`, as follows:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to localhost:22 as 'me'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ybhcdw75C5wG/KnILBWaRnIA+NH8kGBFbi8yUIbUhl0
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/me/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Did you try typing in `yes` at the prompt?

Comment: @grawity I just pressed enter, assuming it would mean "yes". Is it wrong? I also updated the question with the new error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing :

Have you generated own ssh keys ?

```
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
```

this says no public and secret key found..

Plus almost every distribution has now enabled `StrictHostChecking = yes` in /etc/ssh/ssh_config + allowed only ssh2 protocol ( btw. ssh1 allowing ssh1 is dangerous and **totally unsecure**)

And last have you allowed interactive login or only public key auth ?

Comment: I generated keys but I'm not sure if they are in the right place because I'm still getting this error. Could you please provide the commands I need to execute for this? Thanks,

Comment: see `man ssh-keygen` , check /etc/ssh and $HOME/.ssh + permissions for this files

Answer (score 1):

Before your update, you needed to enter "yes" to accept the host key, preferrably after **VERIFYING BY SECONDARY MEANS** that the remote host key matches the key fingerprint displayed.

After your update, you had a cached key corresponding to the old host key (before you regenerated it) in your client `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file, and you need to update or remove the corresponding line in that file.  This is another mechanism prevent man-in-the-middle attacks where someone pretends to be the remote host but of course cannot fake the host key.